# Rails 3. How to create more than one new resource in one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I know how to do that with nested attributes (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true) but now I'm trying to do it without nested attributes.

I would like to have a table with something like this...

```
first_name last_name phone
|        |          |     |
|        |          |     |
|        |          |     |
save
```

So it's a table and there is a field inside every cell. If you add three people to the table and then hit save, there will be 3 people save to the database.

Comment: This can be a relatively complex thing to do well; I recommend you check out the three-part RailsCast starting with [Complex Forms Part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution possible, but you can do something like

```
- 5.times do 
  = fields_for 'users[]' do |f|
    = f.text_field :first_name
```

and then `params[:users]` will contain an array. The controller action will look something like

```
params[:users].each do |user|
  User.create!(user)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up an array of people in the submitted params:

For a regular form (for a single entity) the fields are named like:

```
person[first_name]
person[last_name]
person[phone]
```

and then params[:person] contains that data (params[:person][:first_name], etc)

but what you want is multiple persons.  You indicate this by prepending "[]" to the parameter names, like this:

```
people[][first_name]
people[][last_name]
people[][phone]
people[][first_name]
people[][last_name]
people[][phone]
```

... and when this is submitted, it will be interpreted as a series of person records.  This will show up in params[:people] as an array of persons ( params[:people][0][:first_name], etc)

so then in the controller you would iterate through these records and create new Person objects from each one and save them.